# Why do we need "de" in "un point d’obscur"?

Tags: prépositions, adjectifs

This is an excerpt from L'Étranger by Camus.

> J’ai à peu près compris qu’à son avis il n’y avait qu’**un point d’obscur** dans ma confession, le fait d’avoir attendu pour tirer mon second coup de revolver. Pour le reste, c’était très bien, mais cela, il ne le comprenait pas.

**Question**

Why do we need *d'* (I presume it is *de*) in *un point d'obscur* when it seems to mean *an obscure point*?

Would it be ungrammatical to say simply *un point obscur*?  Would it mean something different?

Comment: Il est bon de noter qu'en dehors de la légère différence sémantique, ce « d' » permet (surtout ?) d'éviter un [hiatus](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/hiatus) désagréable.

Comment: @comet hapax d'ajax The dictionary entry gave me a really good idea of when *de* of this type was used (thanks), but does not seem to suggest that it creates any semantic difference.  Since, however, both Blackhole and guillaume assure me there is one, it must be a very subtle difference, which I will come to appreciate only through repeated encounters in context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il est possible d'avoir un *de* « inverseur » pour marquer que le mot suivant n'a pas la *fonction attendue*, par exemple quand on veut introduire l'attribut et non l’épithète [A, B]. Avec *il y a* (ça peut varier selon le verbe), les adjectifs attributs du sujet réel peuvent être introduits par la préposition *de*, en particulier quand le nom sujet est accompagné d'une quantité, avec un numéral par exemple [A, B], mais ce n'est pas obligatoire [A, B]. Il y a différents usages.

Le *de* est obligatoire quand l'adjectif attribut *précède* son sujet avec le verbe construit sur le modèle *ne...que* ( ...) [C]. Ou quand l'adjectif se rapporte à des trucs comme *quelqu'un/chose/personne/rien/que(relatif ou interrogatif)* etc. [D].<sup>1</sup>

> (A) Il faut qu'il y ait quelque enfant de malade (Proust, *Recherche*)
>   (B) Il y a eu cent hommes de tués ([*Littré*](http://www.littre.org/definition/de), de, 6[7] (sic), et les *Remarques* au bas)
>   (C) Il n'y a d'universel que ce qui est suffisamment grossier pour l'être (Valéry, *Mauvaises pens.*)
>  (D) Il y a quelqu'un de malade.

C'est dans ce sens à mon avis qu'il faut analyser au *TLFi* de à [II.B.3.c.α](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de) (chercher *avoir une heure de libre*). Comme on le voit au *Littré*, et tel qu'on le note au *LBU* (§244, note H2), certains auteurs assimilent la forme primitive à une valeur *partitive* (*un homme de tués* ; *de* serait assimilé à un déterminant si je comprends bien?) ; d'autres parlent de l'*inverseur* auquel on a fait allusion en introduction. Qu'on utilise *de* pour marquer une fonction particulière, un apport d'un élément essentiel du complément mais indépendant de sa nature, ou qu'on réfère à un tout, on ne saurait perdre de vue l'ensemble de la phrase dans l'exemple : *un truc n'était pas clair dans la confession*, de l'avis de quelqu'un. Ce n'est pas qu'il y ait une différence de sens avec ou sans la préposition ici, mais bien une différence de *cohérence* (on a le numéral/il y a/un adjectif attribut du sujet réel), à mon avis.

---

- It is not required here but may be felt as more coherent.
- No.
- Not in my opinion. Some statement or element was strange/not clear, in that confession.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Les propos des deux paragraphes sont basés sur un survol non exhaustif des §§ 244, 1052a dans *Le bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, ed. Duculot, 14ième).</sub>

Comment: Thanks. But questions: 1. (A) seems to imply that *enfant malade* has  la fonction attendue and at least une fonction inattendue? Is *sick child* the expected or the unexpected? And what would be the other meaning? 2. On (B), is *killed men* the expected or the unexpected meaning? What would be the other? 3. On (C), am I supposed to imagine something like this? Aristotle: Only particulars exist. Plato: Oh no, only universals are uncouth enough to exist.

Comment: You're welcome. Please note I do not have expertise which is why I rely on those who do. Good questions. This is not necess. conscious-level semantics. It may be function is about whether something is an innate property or whether the relationship with the noun is more akin to a complementary or transient state. Then with numerals it may be automatically this brings in the idea of the subset. Maybe a picture showing 100 dead men could have a "cent hommes tués" caption; so with _de_ would either be more "a subset of" or an attribution "dead now" i.e. have been killed i.e. _sont morts_... /2

Comment: Indeed _sont morts_ is être + attribut, so _de_ may just be a short way of using a similar construct by implication. Also, function is not semantics. It may be the same semantics are achieved with either forms in a specific case. (C) also feels it could be written as "n'est universel que..." but those have been categorized as being impacted by the position of the adjective or such other specific cases (D). With (A) it feels without _de_ I expect a further complement (ici ?). The subset/quant. idea makes it more whole or natural imho. I'm not clear on what has more influence in each ex. etc.

Answer (score 4):

Les deux sont corrects grammaticalement :

**Il n'y avait qu'un point d'obscur = Il n'y avait qu'un point obscur.**

**Il y a une petite différence de sens:**

*qu'un point obscur* => il y a peut-être plusieurs points obscurs, je n'en vois qu'un (parmi ceux-ci).

*qu'un point d'obscur* => A mon sens, parmi tous les points, il n'y en a qu'un qui est obscur. Il y a une appréciation plus forte.

Cette construction ***nom* + *de* + *adjectif*** est liée à la construction **ne que**, et pourrait être remplacée par *Il n'y avait qu'un point qui soit (ou qui reste) obscur.*

Comment: Thanks. I think *obscure* is perhaps a bad example because things are always obscure *to someone* while perhaps clear *to another*. Suppose we have *Il n'y avait qu'une chambre vide* vs. *Il n'y avait qu'une chambre **de** vide*. Can you please explain the difference in terms of these examples?

Comment: I would have thought that *Il n'y avait qu'une chambre vide* meant that *there was but one empty room*--without any possibility of multiple empty rooms implied in the sentence. (Of course you can always turn out wrong, but that wouldn't mean the sentence already included the possibility.)

Comment: Not many differences. "qu'une chambre de vide": only one is "vide" (among possibly others). "qu'une chambre vide": more ambiguous: one one "chambre", and it is "vide". But the other meaning works also !