# Understanding "je ne lis rien que de monstrueux"

Tags: adjectifs, syntaxe

The question is on *de monstrueux* as highlighted in this passage from Camus's The Stranger.

> Ici, le procureur a essuyé son visage brillant de sueur. Il a dit enfin que son devoir était douloureux, mais qu’il l’accomplirait fermement. Il a déclaré que je n’avais rien à faire avec une société dont je méconnaissais les règles les plus essentielles et que je ne pouvais pas en appeler à ce cœur humain dont j’ignorais les réactions élémentaires. « Je vous demande la tête de cet homme, a-t-il dit, et c’est le cœur léger que je vous la demande. Car s’il m’est arrivé au cours de ma déjà longue carrière de réclamer des peines capitales, jamais autant qu’aujourd’hui, je n’ai senti ce pénible devoir compensé, balancé, éclairé par la conscience d’un commandement impérieux et sacré et par l’horreur que je ressens devant un visage d’homme où je ne lis rien que **de monstrueux**. »

**QUESTION**

I am trying to understand how exactly *de monstrueux* connects to the rest of the sentence syntactically and have come up with these two guesses.  Is either of them correct?

*de monstrueux* is an instance of the *de* + adjective construction as covered in this [other post](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17429/why-do-we-need-de-in-un-point-d-obscur) (so far a statement common to both guess), and:

1. It modifies *rien*.
2. It modifies an implicit substantive between *que* and *de* so that, when it is made explicit, we get something like:  *je ne lis rien que [quelque chose] de monstrueux*

If neither, how should I understand the sentence's formal syntax?

**BACKGROUND**

Guess 1 may suggest *nothing monstrous*, which may appear to be the opposite of what is meant.  But I don't see why we couldn't allow the whole construction *ne rien que de + adjective* to mean *nothing but what is + adjective* while formally allowing the adjective to attach to *rien*.

Comment: It is not a typo. You could say "nothing that is not monstrous/horrendous" or "nothing not monstrous/horrendous" or even "nothing short of monstrous".

Comment: A translation would be "... the horror I feel behind a man's face where I can see nothing but monstrousness". "rien que de" is a litterary form of negation of "rien de". "Ne rien lire de monstueux" means "to see nothing monstrous".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ... je ne lis rien que de monstrueux.

*Négation* + *que de* qui peut être remplacé par une négation partielle ou une exclusion de la négation globale précédente : *Négation* + *qui n'a pas/qui ne soit pas*  ou *pas autre que*.

Langage soutenu qui évite d'utiliser deux négations consécutives (ou une négation et une restriction de cette négation), souvent difficiles à comprendre et qui peuvent être entendues à contre-sens.

- ... je *ne* lis *rien* (que de -->) *qui n'a pas* la conformation d'un monstre [, qui ne soit pas monstrueux].
- ... je *ne* lis *rien* (que de -->) *d'autre que* la manifestation d'un monstre [, qui ne révèle un état monstrueux].

Pour le procureur (qui utilise pour son métier un langage soutenu), chaque détail révèle un monstre, chaque détail est *monstrueux*, on n'y peut voir [lire] *que du monstrueux*, que la manifestation d'un monstre.

Comment: Can I understand your answer to imply the following?  "Guess 1 and 2 are both wrong. The formal syntax of *ne rien que de* is not reductive to anything. It should be taken as a single, opaque unit (i.e. without syntactic parts to it)." An example of a "single, syntactically opaque unit" may be English *not but what* as in, "Not but what I like him."

Answer (score 6):

It is an old literary way of saying: "Je ne lis rien qui ne soit pas monstrueux."