# Le rôle de « de » dans « une heure de libre »

Tags: adjectifs, de

> Il y a eu dix spectateurs de blessés.
>
> Je n'ai pas une heure de libre.

Quel est le rôle de **de** dans ces deux propositions ?

Comment: Voir aussi ces trois questions qui couvrent la même matière : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18630/understanding-je-ne-lis-rien-que-de-monstrueux, https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18817/understanding-tout-ce-que-je-connaissais-de-précis-sur-cet-homme et https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18836/are-de-adjective-and-the-que-de-adjective-essentially-the-same-construct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ces  "de" connotent de niveaux de langue familières. ils ne sont pas nécessaires à la compréhension mais marquent une forme plus décontractée.
on peut se passer du "de" dans la première phrase pour lui donner un ton plus formel.

> "il y a eu dix spectateurs blessés"

Mais dans la seconde on ne peut pas s'en passer, cela sonnerait étrange et on ne l'emploie pas: "je n'ai pas une heure libre"

dans ce cas, "de libre" indique que la personne n'a pas de temps libre. Elle pourrait aussi dire: "je n'ai pas le temps" ou "je ne suis pas libre", ou "je n'ai pas une heure à moi", ou "je n'ai aucune disponibilité".
dire "je n'ai pas une seconde de libre" insiste encore d'avantage sur l'état de précipitation dans lequel la personne se trouve en raccourcissant l'échelle de temps indisponible (une seconde par rapport à une heure).

Comment: Même si j'emploie plus volontiers la forme avec "de", je ne trouve pas "Je n'ai pas une heure libre" étrange...

Comment: Que signifie la première phrase ? Pourquoi tant de phrases sans majuscule initiale ?

Answer (score 4):

Grevisse dixit : *un adjectif ou un participe passé peuvent être accompagnés de "de" **et a alors une indication de quantité**. Usage fréquent dans la langue parlée mais qui n'a rien d'incorrect et se trouve aussi à l'écrit: "Il y eut cent hommes de tués", "il y eut encore quelques mots d'échangés", "c'est une bonne chose de faite", "encore une journée de perdue".*