# C'est ça de gagné

Tags: prépositions, constructions, formulation-idiomatique

Regardant le film français (VOSTF) *Les Lyonnais* j'ai vu la phrase suivante

> C'est toujours ça de gagné.

Est-ce une faute de sous-titrage ? *Ça à gagner* ne serait-elle pas la tournure correcte ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non, l'expression *ça de gagné* est idiomatique et correcte ici.

On veut dire ici qu'une chose a été gagnée, qu'elle n'est pas à la mesure des attentes mais que sa valeur ne doit pas être négligée.

*Ça à gagner* ferait au contraire référence une chose qui n'a pas encore été gagnée (Il y a ça à gagner).

Comment: Merci pour la réponse !

Comment: voir aussi : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31101/le-r%C3%B4le-de-de-dans-une-heure-de-libre . Notant que cet autre fil cf lui-même à 3 autres, je trouve curieux d'observer à quel point cette tournure semble susciter d'interrogations.

Answer (score 1):

It's a commonly used expression, and I'll just add that it comes with several variants such as:

> (This is far from what I expected, but) **c’est toujours ça**.
>
> (Even if there were only a few of them left), **ça serait déjà ça de gagné**.
>
> (I have picked up about 100 Japanese words so far). **C'est toujours ça de pris** (if I need to get through just a few days of a business trip).