# Understanding "Tout ce que je connaissais de précis sur cet homme"

Tags: adjectifs, syntaxe, compléments

The question is on *de précis* as highlighted in this passage from Camus's The Stranger.

> Je me suis souvenu dans ces moments d’une histoire que maman me racontait à propos de mon père. Je ne l’avais pas connu. Tout ce que je connaissais **de précis** sur cet homme, c’était peut-être ce que m’en disait alors maman : il était allé voir exécuter un assassin. Il était malade à l’idée d’y aller. Il l’avait fait cependant et au retour il avait vomi une partie de la matinée.

**Question**

Am I right to think that it modifies *ce* (or perhaps *tout ce*)?

**Background**

I believe it is an instance of the *de* + adjective construction that was covered in [this other post](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17429/why-do-we-need-de-in-un-point-d-obscur).  I just want to make sure *de précis* is not some special phrase with a different syntactic role.

Comment: Good answers have already been made so I'm not adding mine but, to clarify: it's exactly what you think it is, and not a special phrase. Replace "précis" with any adjective that makes sense in context (in the masculine singular) and the sentence still works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's another example of partitive marking on an adjective, but in this case, it is obligatory.

> Je veux une réponse (*de) précise

After *vouloir*, and most verbs, you can't have *de*.

> J'ai quelques objectifs (de) précis

With *avoir*, and other verbs of possession, the addition of *de* is optional and semantically motivated. With *de*, you're implying you have other objectives that aren't precise; without *de* you're not considering those other objectives.

> **Qu'est-ce que** tu as fait *(de) beau aujourd'hui ?
>
> C'est **quelqu'un** *(de) bien
>
> Il y en **beaucoup** *(de) fatigués
>
> **Ce qu'** il a fait *(d')intelligent, c'est d'avoir refusé ce prêt.

When an adjective qualify a relative, indefinite or interrogative pronoun (in bold in the examples above), *de*-marking is obligatory. This is syntactically, rather than semantically, motivated.

In your quote, *précis* modify [Tout ce que je connaissais], a phrase headed by the complex relative pronoun *ce que* and thus has to be marked with *de*.

Answer (score 1):

> Tout ce que je connaissais de précis ... = Tout ce que je connaissais
>   qui soit (qui était) précis ...

*de précis* **ne modifie pas mais précise** *tout ce que* (je connais peut-être d'autres choses, mais pas précises ...).

C'est la même construction que le [post](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17429/why-do-we-need-de-in-un-point-d-obscur) indiqué.

Comment: I believe your distinction between *modifier* and *préciser* tracks what is called the nonrestrict and the restrictive qualifiers? That is, *de précis* here is not characterizing what has already been fully identified, but is part of the identification (specification)?

Answer (score 0):

In english it is said in the way of "what I knew (of this man) precisely", or "what I precisely knew of this man".

Referring to the exactitude of their knowledge.

Comment: Ça ne répond pas à la question.